# I have a RequireJs (main.js), but I just want to affect only footer not body or other pages

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

This is a example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <p class="mainJs">I am Body</p>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <p class="mainJs">I am footer</p>
    </footer>
    <!--This script only can work in footer -->
    <script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script>
</html>
```

This is my main.js

```
$('.mainJs').css('color','red');
```

[This is my output, body will affect by main.js too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK4jm.png) 
The problem is that main.js will affect both (body and footer), but I dont want main.js work in my body, can I just only affect in my footer(only in html i can edit, because in my real case manjs have to use in other pages)?

Comment: Can you give an example of how it changes your body?

Comment: Hi @vincenzopalazzo I added my example, I hope this will make clearly thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
$("footer:first").css('color','red');
--or
$("footer:last").css('color','red');
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, that can work but if I cant changed the main.js how can I do this in .html, eg: <script data-main=""> change this or something, because only .html I can change

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">function setFooterColor(){ $("footer:first").css('color','red'); }</script>`

Comment: sorry mybe I am not cleary my question, this script $('.mainJs').css('color','red'); already in main.js, but i dont want main.js affect my body, and how can i do this in html

Comment: try `<p class="mainJs anycss">I am Body</p>` , because $('.mainJs') is a css selector.